# How to write sql query in php with if statement in WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, where-clause

How do I write a SQL query with an if statement in the WHERE part of a query?

Here is my sql:

```
$sql = 'SELECT First, Second, 
           Third,Fifth, Status, Isik_id, Comments, Code
    FROM Persons WHERE  Status = 1 && Third = "'.$whoislogged.'" ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1';
```

The `Third = "'.$whoislogged.'"` is a word what comes from session.

If $whoislogged exists and is equal to Third then the query should be like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT First, Second, Third,Fifth, Status, Isik_id, Comments, Code
        FROM Persons 
WHERE  Status = 1 && Third = "'.$whoislogged.'" ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1';
```

But if the $whoislogged dosent appear then the query should be like:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT First, Second, 
           Third,Fifth, Status, Isik_id, Comments, Code
    FROM Persons WHERE  Status = 1 ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1';
```

So how can I put all this into one query?

Comment: You have to build your query dynamically. and also you should use prepared statements.

Comment: I fail to understand your problem. If I get it right, you can just check in php if $whoislogged exists and create the desired query.

Comment: @Homeless Person Don't think so... looks more like a dynamic query build or something.

Comment: @zozo my apologies. Read the question real quick and didn't interpret everything correctly. Still don't really understand his question by the description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it in query itself.

```
WHERE  Status = 1 and if(Third = "'.$whoislogged.'", Third = "'.$whoislogged.'" , 1=1)
```

the condition part will check third is match with $whoislogged if it's true then add id as condition otherwise omit this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a new variable that contains the `Third` statement

```
if ( !empty($whoislogged) ) $third = "AND Third = ". $whoislogged;
else $third = "";

$sql = 'SELECT First, Second, 
           Third,Fifth, Status, Isik_id, Comments, Code
    FROM Persons WHERE  Status = 1 '. $third .' ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1';
```

It is not the most efficient way but it works

Comment: How to i access the THIRD before the query is made?

Comment: @JannoS what do you mean?

Comment: I have: require('connect.php'); and then comes the sql part on of the thing. How can i check if row equals smth before i select the tabel and collumns

Comment: @JannoS Make another query that selects `Thrid` , get its value and compare